# How do I scan less chars than defined into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

I've encountered a problem while trying to scan chars into an array.

This is the scan loop -

```
char letter[6] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    scanf(" %c", &letter[i]);
}
```

The desired result is that if the input is shorter than 6 every element which doesn't receive a value from `scanf` while remains 0.

However if I try to input for example 3 chars I cannot continue in the program.

On the other hand when I try to input 3 chars from txt file the program works and I achieve the desired result.

I was wondering what is the correct way to fix this issue.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "if I try to input for example 3 chars"  Did you press 4 keys for that?  Hint, look for the <enter> key.

Comment: I've tried entering 1-5 chars directly in many combinations however only when i enter the input via a txt file the program runs, otherwise the scanf will wait until I enter the remaining chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code fails to detect `'\n'` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) due to space in format.

`" "` in `scanf(" %c",&letter[i]);` consumes and discards all white space including `'\n'` so code loses a way to detect end-of-line.

Instead check if scan failed (`stdin` closed or rare input error) or if a `'\n'` was read, then break the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
  char ch;
  if (scanf("%c", &ch) != 1 || ch == '\n') {
    break;
  }
  letter[i] = (char) ch;
}
```

---

To insure `letter[]` is a *string*, leave the last element as a *null character*.

```
// for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
```